# Swift out of range.... with tableView[indexPath]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

I'm getting trouble with out of `range` error...

The error occurs in `cell.creditLabel.text = numOfDays[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] + "days"`.

And if I put `tableView.reloadData()` after `cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]`

then nothing shows up in the simulator...

How can I fix this problem..?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.nameArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : MoneyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyTableViewCell


    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.creditLabel.text = numOfDays[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] + "days"
    cell.levelLabel.text = creditArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: And if I put tableView.reloadData() after cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] then nothing show up in simulator... 

You should not put table-view reload in it. 
It will run in an infinite loop then.

You should not force type cast to NSIndexPathm index path row will work

Comment: *"How can I fix this problem..?"* – That is called *debugging.* How many elements has the array? Which element are you trying to access? Why has the array less elements than you think is has? ... Think!

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I'm pretty newbie in programmer world so I will practice more. Thanks for advice....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check your arrays. From what I can see here, `numOfDays` have less elements then `nameArray`. Also, while you are there check `creditArray` as well :)

Also, cast to `NSIndexPath` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I checked debug area and figured out I have 14 elements in nameArray. It should be 7 atoms in name Array & numOfDays but I still have no idea why there is 14.

Comment: Anyway i just changed nameArray.count to creditArray.count then now is working. Thank you again :)

Comment: Probably you have added to nameArray twice. Double check data preparation function(s).

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out but hard to find. I'm wondering that if i use tableView.reloadData(), does it mean that tableView() with cellforRow call again?

Comment: Yes, reloadData will call cellforRow

Comment: My goodness, Finally I figured out. I called reloadData in viewDidLoad() with another function, I thought reloadData wasn't problem, but it is. Thank you! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Please be VERY cautions - You should NOT build data for arrays in any of tableView functions...

Answer (score 1):

Number of elements in "numOfDays" array are less than number of elements in "nameArray" array

Comment: I think posting the answer which is already posted is not a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Check that the arrays have the correct amount of items:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.nameArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : MoneyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyTableViewCell


    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]

    if numOfDays.count < indexPath.row {
        cell.creditLabel.text = numOfDays[indexPath.row] + "days"
    }

    if creditArray.count < indexPath.row {
        cell.levelLabel.text = creditArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Also, I have removed the unnecessary casting of indexPath and the layoutIfNeeded (the cell will always draw again, since it is new).