# Fatal error: Array index out of range in swift2 version

Tags: ios, swift

Please help with the error I have
on this line:

```
cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row] //error array  index out of range
```

This is my declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var names = ["Anna","aanal"]
    var petnames = ["Anu","aalu"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row] //error array  index out of range
            cell.petname.text = petnames[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code on which array is being used to display the tableview? are you using names array or petnames array?

Comment: add numberOfRow method also in question .

Comment: Please display the definition of the variable `names`

Comment: You may access the value from the array list which is not available. For e.g.: If you have 4 cell in tableview and you have only 3 values in the array, in that situation it throws exception like index out of range

Comment: I see you have two different arrays; `names` and `petNames`; this is risky, since if the arrays get out of sync you can have errors such as the one you have experienced.  It is better to have a single array of Structs, each with a `name` and a `petName`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097448/swift-out-of-range-with-tableviewindexpath.

Comment: Your array only has 2 elements while your numberOfRowsInSection method returns 3. Either change it to 2 or add 3 elements in your array

Comment: ohh got it i have return 3 when i have only two value in array i find answer  thank you very much  for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

I think your are passed  `petnames`  in `numberOfRowsInSection` and names and petnames count are also different so this problem occurs .

**Solution**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if names.count == petnames.count{
            return petnames.count

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**OR**

You have passed more numberOfRowsInSection then array.count

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2 or names.count
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your array only has 2 elements while your numberOfRowsInSection method returns 3. Either change it to 2 or add 3 elements in your array

The ideal way is to change

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return names.count
}
```

But usually dont work with 2 arrays and create a Entity object having name and petname as elements and then have an array of your entity class to populate tableview

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the count of array

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}
```

Comment: If you are going to copy my comment to make an answer, at least go to the trouble of providing a complete answer including the definition of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 values in your arrays `names` and `petnames`. However, there are 3 rows in your Table View. So, if the 3rd row of the table view is selected, it will be out of range of the array as there is no 3rd element in the arrays.

The solution is to make your `names` array and `petnames` array contain 3 elements:

```
var names = ["Anna","aanal", "boo"]
var petnames = ["Anu","aalu", "bo"]
```

or to return 2 rows in your table view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

The **best** way is to return the count of the arrays (if the count of both arrays are different, return nothing):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if names.count == petnames.count {
        return names.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Anna","aanal"]  // you have 2 elemnts
var petnames = ["Anu","aalu"]

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return 3 // you have returned 3 but it should be 2

    // it should be
    return 2
    //or 
    //  return names.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row] //you got error because you are trying to get 3 element from array where as there are only 2 elements 
    cell.petname.text = petnames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

It is better if you use your arrayname.count